# Ranking is not updated by serial

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to update my rank column by sorting order. But it is not sorted like that way.

[image]

I want Ranking will be 1 for first row and 2 for 2nd row.

**user_teams**

user_id | match_id | team_earning_point

[image]

**user_team_contests**

user_id |user_team_id |contest_id

[image]

In both table **Id** is primary key

here is my sql code:

```
Set @a=0;
SELECT  u_t.id,u_t.match_id,u_t.team_earning_point, @a:=@a+1 as ranking
FROM user_teams AS u_t, user_team_contests as u_t_c
WHERE u_t_c.contest_id=21  AND u_t.id = u_t_c.user_team_id
ORDER BY u_t.team_earning_point DESC, u_t_c.created_at ASC
```

Where to change my code for get accurate result?

Comment: Which one is the primary key? post the both table data

Comment: update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in MySQL are finicky.  You should do the `order by` *before* assigning the variable:

```
SELECT ut.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
FROM (SELECT u_t.id u_t.match_id, u_t.team_earning_point 
      FROM user_teams u_t JOIN
           user_team_contests u_t_c
           ON u_t.id = u_t_c.user_team_id
      WHERE u_t_c.contest_id = 21 
      ORDER BY u_t.team_earning_point DESC, u_t_c.created_at ASC
     ) ut CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params;
```

You'll notice that I also fixed your archaic join syntax.  You should always use `JOIN`/`ON` to express joins.

Of course, in MySQL 8+, you would just use:

```
row_number() over (partition by u_t_c.contest_id order by u_t.team_earning_point DESC, u_t_c.created_at) as ranking
```

Comment: It’s pretty much in the manual *”The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.”*

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . That issue actually has nothing to do with this particular problem.  There is only one expression using the ranking variable.  This is an issue of the `order by` (and `group by` by the way) and when the variable calculations occur relative to that operation.

Comment: more or less it does as you force the evaluation for user variable  expressions on the outer sql instead off relative to the order by as MySQL does not guarantee when the user variable is run it can be after the order or before the order for a record.

Comment: "finicky"? I'd rather say "unpredictable". Some MariaDB versions will ignore any ORDER BY clause in a subquery without LIMIT. And sometimes it works without a subquery (when the ORDER BY clause is using an index). And for some MySQL (5.7.x) versions your query might not work due to "propagation" of ORDER BY to the outer query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . .  I have not seen this *not work* in MySQL (I don't know about MariaDB); but I think any propagation of `ORDER BY` would have been introduced only in the later versions of 5.7, so I might not have been exposed to it.  I have seen that the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is necessary, on the other hand.